# How to change what the back button does in dart

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, lib

How can I change the function of the back button in dart flutter
[image]

I really didn't try anything because tbh, i didn't find what to try

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need simply to override the `leading` property in the `AppBar` with a new `IconButton`, then set your specific method:

```
AppBar(
 leading: IconButton(
  onPressed: () {
   print("clicked");
  },
  icon: Icon(Icons.abc),
  ),
 ),
```